# 2 variables "variable weighting" function

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, combinations

I have two variables $X,Y \in [0,1]$ and want to output some kind of weighted indicator based on these two. X is a raw indicator value where a low value indicates good health, and Y measures uncertainty, a low value indicating the value is believed to be certain/confidence. I don't know how to formulate an equation that combine the two into the $Z$ weighted indicator.

I have a boolean formulation of $Z = X \text{ or } Y$ that combines the two but I don't know how to transition it to the real number domain in my mind and keep it in the $[0,1]$ range.

The $Z$ weighted indicator must measure both the value of $X$ and Y, but the importance/weight of $X$ is dependent on having a low uncertainty $Y$.

As the 4 binary combinations:

$$X=0 \wedge Y=0 \implies Z=0 \text{ (good indicator value and low uncertainty, that's good)}$$

$$X=0 \wedge Y=1 \implies Z=1 \text{ (good indicator value and high uncertainty, that's bad)}$$

$$X=1 \wedge Y=0 \implies Z=1 \text{ (bad indicator value and low uncertainty, that's bad)}$$

$$X=1 \wedge Y=1 \implies Z=1 \text{ (bad indicator value and high uncertainty, that's bad)}$$

Thank you.

Comment: A simple polynomial solution would be $ z = 1-(1-x)(1-y)=x+y-xy$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic [fuzzy logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic) approach has "truth" on a sliding scale between $0$ (false) and $1$ (true). This defines the logical operation "**and**" by multiplication, so that, for example, two almost-true values will have a slightly lower but largely true result. The logical operation "**not**" is simply a reversal in range, i.e **not** $X := (1-X)$.

Your logical "**or**" operation can then be defined by these two operations through the normal rules of boolean logic:
$$\newcommand{\or}{\mathop{\mathbf{or}}} \newcommand{\and}{\mathop{\mathbf{and}}}  \newcommand{\not}{\mathop{\mathbf{not}}} 
X \or Y  = \not( (\not X) \and (\not Y)) \\
=\not( (1- X) \and (1- Y))\\
=\not( (1- X)(1- Y) ) \\
=1- (1- X)(1- Y) 
$$

This outcome may not immediately reflect the reality of the relative weights you want to attach to the value as against the uncertainty, but the mapping of measured values into the $[0,1]$ space could potentially be adjusted to accommodate that reality check as necessary.